# Spring Batch Error : JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, java-17

I am upgrading Java from 8 to 17 and Spring boot to 2.7.0 ..the application builds fine .. but when I run I get the below error:

Here is a snippet of the application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/abc;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    name:
    username:
    poolName: AbcConnectionPool
    initializationFailTimeout: -1
  jpa:
    database: H2
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.show_sql: true
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop #update #create-drop
      #hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

hibernate.import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor
flyway:
# Before enabling set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
enabled: false

**I have remove the @EnableBatchProcessing from the Batch file**

```
@Configuration
public class BatchJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource abcDataSource;
```

................

**This is where the beans are defined **

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
    
    public static final int JPA_PAGE_SIZE = 1000;
    public static final int DATA_CHUNK_SIZE = 100;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public HikariConfig abcHikariConfig() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "abcDataSource")
    public DataSource abcDataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(abcHikariConfig());
    }
}
```

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-16 17:44:19.195 ERROR 35316 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at com.intrum.abc.Application.main(Application.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42102-212]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.isJobInstanceExists(SimpleJobRepository.java:93) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:206) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:198) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42102-212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8376) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8347) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8336) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1883) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2359) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2810) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2917) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2800) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2667) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2646) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2639) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2632) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2593) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:691) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:568) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1645) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 42 common frames omitted

Comment: can you try adding property `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`. also, you can refer to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631547/spring-batch-postgres-error-relation-batch-job-instance-does-not-exist